# how to validate aadhar card in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
aadharValid(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      var re = new RegExp(/\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/);
      this.aadharInput = control.value;
      let isValid = re.test(this.aadharInput);
      if (!isValid)
        return { 'aadharValid': { isValid } }
      else
        return null;
    };
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item> 
    <ion-label floating>Aadhar Card Number</ion-label> 
    <ion-input type="tel" maxlength="12" [(ngModel)]="user.aadhar" spellcheck="false" minlength="12" maxlength="12" formControlName="aadhar"></ion-input> 
</ion-item> 
<ion-item no-lines *ngIf="( user.get('aadhar').hasError('aadharValid')) && user.get('aadhar').touched"> 
    <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('aadhar').hasError('aadharValid') && user.get('aadhar').touched"> Please enter valid Aadhar NO </div> 
</ion-item>
```

I got validation but If i give proper input means still error shows

Comment: <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Aadhar Card Number</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" maxlength="12" [(ngModel)]="user.aadhar" spellcheck="false" minlength="12" maxlength="12" formControlName="aadhar"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item no-lines *ngIf="( user.get('aadhar').hasError('aadharValid')) && user.get('aadhar').touched">
        <div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('aadhar').hasError('aadharValid') && user.get('aadhar').touched">
          Please enter valid Aadhar NO
        </div>

      </ion-item>

Comment: [edit] the post instead of adding in comments